# Saving a list of items in Application State ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, state, global-asax

I'm having a bit of trouble with knowing how I can save items from a list I have in Application state in the global.asax as- Application[""].

My controller basically takes in some user input, I then pass this to another classes Method as parameters it gets added to a list all the time. This data thats getting added to the list I want to store it, but without using a db. By using Application State. . I have been instantiating this class and calling its method to return the list of items but I dont think Application State is saving it.

Here is what I have so far. .

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


        TimeLineInformation t = new TimeLineInformation();
        IList<SWTimeEnvInfoDTO> g = t.getInfo();

        Application["AppID"] =  g;
    }
```

^ Global.asax

```
        IList<SWTimeEnvInfoDTO> result = new List<SWTimeEnvInfoDTO>();

    public  void returnTimeLineInfo(string SWrelease, string EnvName, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate) {


        SWTimeEnvInfoDTO myDTO = new SWTimeEnvInfoDTO();
        myDTO.softwareReleaseName = SWrelease;
        myDTO.environmentName = EnvName; 
        myDTO.StartDate = SDate;
        myDTO.EndDate = EDate;

        result.Add(myDTO);

        getInfo();


    }


    public IList<SWTimeEnvInfoDTO> getInfo() {

        return result;

    }
```

^ class im calling

The SWTimeEnvInfoDTO type has get and set methods for the data.

I am calling the application from a View as well. It works with a string

Application["AppID"] = "fgt";

and shows this once i read it from my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated*: You should use casting to retrieve variable you have saved at Application, and save it if it has changed:

```
IList<SWTimeEnvInfoDTO> result = Application["AppID"] != null ? (IList<SWTimeEnvInfoDTO>)Application["AppID"] : new List<SWTimeEnvInfoDTO>(); // retrieve data  

result.Add(...);               // add some new items
Application["AppID"] = result; // save added values
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still debigging though and its not returning new items I've added in the list to the Application state for storage, it reads the initial value which is null but as I add more items, nothing . .?

Comment: You should 1) extract current value from app storage 2) make changes 3) put changed value to app storage